# Two names on check

Tags: check

so i don't understand the check I got. On the "pay to the order of" section, it writes my school's name. But on the "for" section it writes my name. So can I deposit this check to my bank account. Or do I have to give it my school and than what happens to my money?

Comment: Who gave you the check? What is it for?

Comment: Most likely, the school can sign the check over to you. That way, they don't have to go through the trouble of cashing the check and then issuing you another check.

Comment: If the check is intended to cover an expense you owe the school, they will probably credit you with a payment after they cash the check and it clears.

Comment: If this is in the US, the FOR line is comment only. You cannot cash or deposit that check.

Comment: @mkennedy Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: Is this check intended to be a payment for tuition or similar? Who did it come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the person on the "Pay to the Order" line can deposit the check. The to line doesn't Change anything. It sounds like the check was written with the intention that the school deposits the check, not you.

You will need to get them to sign it over to you, or deposit it and give you the funds.